# listview problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check if an a field is not empty, and show a link?
i tried something like this but i get error.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <h2><%#Eval("NC_Title") %></h2>
    <%#Eval("NC_StartDate") %>
    <p><%#Eval("NC_Abstract") %></p>
    <%if(Eval("NC_Description").ToString().Length > 0)
      {
          %><a href="">Read more...</a><%
      }%>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

when i tried to use the example in answer below it's work
<a href="" runat="server" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("NC_Description") as string) %>'>Read more...</a>

but i don't want to see the asp.net control ID in the source :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can put the entire link into databinding:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <h2><%#Eval("NC_Title") %></h2>
    <%#Eval("NC_StartDate") %>
    <p><%#Eval("NC_Abstract") %></p>
    <%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("NC_Description") as string) ? "<a href=\"\">Read more...</a>" : string.Empty %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the "read more" link a control (ie. add `runat="server"`), and bind it's visibility:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <h2><%#Eval("NC_Title") %></h2>
    <%#Eval("NC_StartDate") %>
    <p><%#Eval("NC_Abstract") %></p>
    <a href="" runat="server" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("NC_Description") as string) %>'>Read more...</a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: it's work but i preffer to use simple link without runat server.

Comment: yes, but you are trying to mix script blocks with data binding, and it is most likely not going to work. besides putting runat="server" on the link only creates a literal control and you will get no extra markup rendered (right?)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `NC_Description` is null. In this case when you try to invoke `ToString` method from a null object it gives you `NullReferenceException`. Try to change it like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <h2><%#Eval("NC_Title") %></h2>
    <%#Eval("NC_StartDate") %>
    <p><%#Eval("NC_Abstract") %></p>
    <%if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("NC_Description") as string))
      {
          %><a href="">Read more...</a><%
      }%>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```